# difficulty accessing root in angular 9 app

Tags: angular, components

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.component.css' in '/home/tjay/produce-market/src/app'
ERROR in ./src/app/produce/create-produce/create-produce.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './create-produce.component.css' in '/home/tjay/produce-market/src/app/produce/create-produce'
ERROR in ./src/app/produce/produce-item/produce-item.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './produce-item.component.css' in '/home/tjay/produce-market/src/app/produce/produce-item'
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Please show us the base-href in index.html   and  the comlete package.json.  When does the error occure "ng start" ? Or after build/deployment ?

Comment: Is it because you've changed the styles to `scss` in `angular.json` ?

Comment: I FOUND THE ERROR, WHEREAS I CHOOSE SCSS, I WAS STILL POINTING TO .CSS FILE. APOLOGIES

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should really provide some code example that reproduces this error, so users can help you easier. Without any code we are really just guessing.

If I would have to take a guess i would say your error lies here:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'create-produce',
  templateUrl: './produce-item.component.html'',
  styleUrls: ['./produce-item.component.css'] // problem lies here
})
```

Either the path you use for your css files is incorrect or the file extension is not correct. By default Angular uses .scss not .css. Maybe try changing that and report back?

Answer (score 0):

The file name (or extension such as .css, .scss) might be different in the `styleUrls` specified in the `@Component`, and the actual file.